# SQLite connection string cannot contain a comma?

Tags: sqlite

I'm getting an error from SQLite when the connection string contains a comma. I don't have full control over where the database will end up, so it's possible a user will place it into a directory containing arbitrary characters. In this case, it appears that the presence of a comma (,) in the path causes an error when connecting. Here is the connection string:

```
Data Source=C:/Users/Dan/AppData/LocalLow/Gravia Software, LLC/Gravia/exampleDatabase.db;
```

This results in the following exception when trying to connect:

```
ArgumentException: Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "LLC/Gravia/exampleDatabase.db"
```

It appears that the presence of the comma in the connection string is the issue. I've tried escaping the command (\,), wrapping the whole thing in quotes, but it doesn't seem to matter. Any ideas?

Edit:

The actual code I was executing comes from this page: https://ornithoptergames.com/how-to-set-up-sqlite-for-unity/

```
var dbPath = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/exampleDatabase.db";
using (var conn = new SqliteConnection(dbPath)) {
    conn.Open(); // Error occurs here
    // etc
}
```

I tried changing out URI=file: for Data Source=, as the result was the same.

Comment: `sqlite3` from windows command line has no problem acessing a database whose name contains spaces or commas, as long as the name is wrapped in `"`.

Comment: I'm more inclined to blame something in your code that can't handle spaces in filenames. But since you don't actually show the relevant code...

Comment: Sorry, I added the specific code. Given DinoCoderSaurus' statement that this works for him, perhaps there's something up with Unity's implementation of this. I'll continue to pursue this on the Unity forums. Thanks.

Comment: In ODBC connection strings, entire values can be quoted with curly brackets, but I don't know if this uses the same syntax.

Comment: Same problem here, did you find something more out about that, @Dan?

Answer (score 1):

You can escape unsupported characters in ODBC connection variables using curly-brackets (`{}`).

So wrap your variable, like below

```
Data Source={C:/Users/Dan/AppData/LocalLow/Gravia Software, LLC/Gravia/exampleDatabase.db};
```

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-escape-special-characters-imports-odbc-connection-string)

Comment: This works when semicolon in path, kind of 

`string DBPath= $@"C:\QA_suck\add ;\in\DB\path";
conn = new SQLConnection($"Data Source = '{{system.IO.Path.GetFullPath(DBPath)}}');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

```
"Data Source=" + "C:/Users/Dan/AppData/LocalLow/Gravia Software," + "LLC/Gravia/exampleDatabase.db";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this way:

```
        var currDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/DB/"));

        SqliteConnection dbcon = null;
        try
        {
            dbcon = new SqliteConnection(_Connection);
            dbcon.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currDir);
        }
```